# Scrapy Double Extracts in cells

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this scripts that works fine I think for what I want but I face one problem.

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Offers'
start_urls = ['https://www.invia.cz/direct/community_login/ajax-login/?ac_email=zisi%40electratours.cz&ac_password=electra1999']


def start_requests(self):
    return [scrapy.FormRequest("https://www.invia.cz/direct/community_login/ajax-login/?ac_email=zisi%40electratours.cz&ac_password=electra1999",
                               formdata={'user': '', 'pass': ''},
                               callback=self.after_login)]


def after_login(self, response):

        return scrapy.Request(url="https://dovolena.invia.cz/direct/tour_search/ajax-next-boxes/?nl_country_id%5B%5D=28&nl_locality_id%5B%5D=19&d_start_from=08.03.2017&d_end_to=28.05.2017&nl_transportation_id%5B%5D=3&nl_ck_id%5B%5D=62&sort=nl_sell&page=1&getOptionsCount=true&base_url=https%3A%2F%2Fdovolena.invia.cz%2F",callback=self.logged_in)

def logged_in(self, response):
    data=json.loads(response.text)

    sel=Selector(text=data['boxes_html'])
    ag=Selector(text=data['boxes_html'])
    ko=sel.css('li.hotel-box').extract()  

    for x in range(0,len(ko)):
      sel=Selector(text=ko[x])

      name=sel.css('span.name::text').extract_first()

      data=sel.xpath('//li/@data-content-value').extract()

      IC=[json.loads(d)["nl_hotel_id"] for d in data]

      for x in range(0,len(data)):
       IC[x]=''.join(map(str, IC[x]))

      ICn=[j.strip() for j in IC]

      print (ICn[x])

      url1="https://dovolena.invia.cz/direct/tour_search/ajax-next-box-rows/"

      url2=ICn[x]

      url3="/?nl_country_id%5B0%5D=28&nl_locality_id%5B0%5D=19&d_start_from=08.03.2017&d_end_to=28.05.2017&nl_transportation_id%5B0%5D=3&nl_ck_id%5B0%5D=62&sort=nl_sell&page=2&boxPage=1"

      url_final=url1+url2+url3

      print(url_final)

      request=scrapy.Request(url=str(url_final),callback=self.hotel)

      request.meta["name"]=name

      yield request


    next_page = ag.css("a.next::attr(data-page)").extract_first()
    print("Page %s -1" %next_page)
    url = re.sub('page=\d+', 'page=' + next_page, response.url)
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.logged_in)

def hotel(self,response):
  names = response.meta['name']
  dates=response.css("strong.date").extract()
  prices=response.css("strong.orange").extract()
  airport=response.css("p.info>span::attr(title)").extract()
  meal=response.css("span.blue::text").extract()
  minute=response.css("span.symptom::text").extract()




  yield{


   "Hotel":names,  
   "Dates":dates,
   "Airport":airport,
   "MealType":meal,
   "Minute":minute
  }

  if(response.css("a.next")):
    next_page = response.css("a.next::attr(rel)").extract_first()
    url = re.sub('boxPage=\d+', 'boxPage=' + next_page, response.url)
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.hotel)
  else:
    return
```

When I crawl and get them all in a csv output I see two "scraped" data in a single cell and I can't seem to find a way how to fix this or why it's happening.

Comment: can you share one output example? (two lines of the csv file maybe)

Comment: @eLRuLL Here is the link of the example csv [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1bNXrCh4hqsWnpHNUpQQnh4d1E)

Comment: what's the problem with the output? please give examples

Comment: For example in the first row you see two times FM and every value when it should extract only once or in the dates you see two extractions and it should be in a different one. I hope you understand what I'm trying to say

Comment: the xpath should match multiple nodes in that xpath, try `minute=response.css("span.symptom::text").extract_first()`